# Average Account Age

Tags: plugins, users, user-meta, user-registration

I'm trying to see if there is a way to find an average age of user accounts which came through my wordpress site not including the age of the administrator account.

When I say age I don't mean their actual birth age but the tenure of their account.

Is there a simple way to determine this?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress records when a user was registered in the `$wpdb->users` (usually `wp_users`) table in the column `user_registered`. So you can use that to calculate the average account age. There's no internal function for this, so you'll have to use `$wpdb` directly.

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4312552/1031898) has some good info about calculating the average of a series of dates. Translated to WordPress functions and such:

```
<?php
function wpse106440_avg_account_age($ignore=1)
{
   global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MIN(user_registered)) / (COUNT(ID) - 1)"
        . " FROM {$wpdb->users}"
        . " WHERE ID <> %d",
        $ignore
    ));
}
```

If you're admin user's ID is `1`, then...

```
<?php
$avg_age = wpse106440_avg_account_age(1);
```

... would be the average account age excluding the admin.

If you, say, want to exclude all administrator level users, you'll have to fetch users via `get_users` of that role then exclude the array of those ID's (eg `NOT IN`). WP doesn't have separate tables for roles and caps, making it difficult to query by them in SQL directly -- a users capabilities are stored as a serialized array.

Comment: In my database, the oldest user registered on `2013-03-26` and the newest on `2013-05-31`, yet this function gives an average duration of `15.7143`. With today being `2013-07-14`, the minimum possible value should be 44-- calculated with `DATEDIFF`.  This is returning an average duration of just over 1/3 the age of the shortest actual duration rather than returning something between the shortest (44) and the longest (110) as it should.

Answer (score 0):

As @chrisguitarguy stated, there is no internal function to do this. Below is my suggested solution. It should ignore any user with the 'administrator' role.

```
function user_duration_wpse_106440() {
  global $wpdb;
  $admins = get_users(array('role' => 'administrator','fields' => 'ID'));
  $today = date_create();
  $sql = "SELECT user_registered FROM {$wpdb->users}";
  if (!empty($admins)) {
    $sql .= " WHERE ID NOT IN (".implode(',',$admins).")";
  }
  $users = $wpdb->get_col($sql);
  foreach ($users as $k => $v) {
    $age = date_diff($today,date_create($v));
    $users[$k] = $age->days;
  }
  // return on the average as a string
  // return array_sum($users) / count($users);

  // alternate; return both average and total
  return array(
     'average' => (array_sum($users) / count($users)),
     'total'   => count($users)
  );
}
// echo user_duration_wpse_106440();
$user_duration = user_duration_wpse_106440();
echo $user_duration['average'];
echo '<br>';
echo $user_duration['total'];
```

This gives a sane average when tested on my server. It returns an answer in "days", by the way.

I am toying with some variants. I may post other versions.

Comment: This is interesting, how & where would I put this piece of code?

Comment: Put the function definition in `functions.php` or a plugin file. Use the function-- last line-- wherever you need it.

Comment: perfect seems to bring up the average right. Is there a way to echo out the qty of how many accounts this calculation is being made?

Comment: You would have to return an array. I can edit the answer. Give me a minute.

Comment: seems like I'm getting a parse error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/functions.php on line 174

Comment: Fixed. It was missing a semi-colon. That is what I get for trying to edit "live".

Comment: I implemented the above and corrected the $suer_duration['total']; to $user_duration['total']; but the total users through the system doesn't print anything

Comment: "...total users through the system doesn't print anything..."-- yes it does. Put a `<br>`, or other characters, between the `echo`s.